# Not able to scan file locate at root folder using sonar scanner

Tags: drupal-7, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am using sonarqube and sonarqube scannner for my Drupal project. As drupal project is multi-module project and has many custom modules developed under custom_module folder.

I am scanning only custom folders listed under folder custom_module.
Suppose there are 3 custom modules I want to scan...
custom_module1, custom_module2, custom_module3 and sub-folders inc,modules and templates under them...
My sonar-project.properties file looks like

```
# Root project information
sonar.projectKey=MyProjectKey
sonar.projectName=My Project
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

# Some properties that will be inherited by the modules
sonar.sources=inc,modules,templates
sonar.php.file.suffixes=php,module,inc
# List of the module identifiers
sonar.modules=custom_module1,custom_module2,custom_module3

# Properties can obviously be overriden for
# each module - just prefix them with the module ID
custom_module1.sonar.projectName=custom_module1
custom_module2.sonar.projectName=custom_module2
custom_module3.sonar.projectName=custom_module3
```

Now everything is working fine and it is scanning all files except .module file at root of each module. e.g. custom_module1/custom_module1.module

What should I add in properties file so that it includes .module file?

Comment: Is that your full properties file?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam Yes thats complete sonar properties file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for above problem. By adding separate 'sources' for each module will resolve the issue.

So updated sonar-project.properties file :-

```
# Root project information
sonar.projectKey=MyProjectKey
sonar.projectName=My Project
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

# Some properties that will be inherited by the modules
sonar.php.file.suffixes=php,module,inc
# List of the module identifiers
sonar.modules=custom_module1,custom_module2,custom_module3

# Properties can obviously be overriden for
# each module - just prefix them with the module ID
custom_module1.sonar.projectName=Custom Module1
custom_module2.sonar.projectName=Custom Module2
custom_module3.sonar.projectName=Custom Module3

custom_module1.sonar.sources=inc,modules,templates,custom_module1.module
custom_module2.sonar.sources=inc,modules,templates,custom_module2.module
custom_module3.sonar.sources=inc,modules,templates,custom_module3.module
```

Using this one can add files at root folder.

Answer (score 0):

you can add folders to scan with `sonar.sources`

if you would like to scan all the files `sonar.sources=.`

I think the way you can do that is add the dot to scan all of files/folders and add a new line for exlusions `sonar.exclusions=` so it is going to skip the folder/files you which are after the exlusions.

Comment: Okay...I added '.' in sources and added files and folders in sonar.exclusions. But now scanner giving me error like " File ******** can't be indexed twice. Please check that inclusion/exclusion patterns produce disjoint sets for main and test files"

Comment: sorry for confusing then, haven't used it for a while

maybe it is working the way you can add folders only to one of them, since "." (dot) means all the folders and when you add a folder/file to exlusions it confuses sonarqube

Try it it without using "." (dot) at sonar.sources and use folder/file names instead